# how to display data select option using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

this code is working but he execute when i change in the select box .
i need to display in load first option

```
      $("select[name='annuellement_name']").change(function(){
                      var annuellement_Id = $(this).find('option:checked').val();
                      var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
                      $.ajax({
                          url: "{{route('dashboard.countyears')}}",
                          method: 'POST',
                          data: {'annuellementId':annuellement_Id, _token:token},
                          success: function(data) {
                            var datayr =JSON.parse(data);
                            jQuery('#morris-bar-chart-year').length && jQuery('#morris-bar-chart-year').empty();
                            jQuery('#morris-bar-chart-year').length && Morris.Bar({
                          element: 'morris-bar-chart-year',
                          data:datayr,
                          xkey: 'y',
                          ykeys: ['nombre'],
                          labels: ['NOMBRE'],
                          barColors:['#ffaa11', '#b4c1d7', '#fcc9ba','#ffaa11'],
                          hideHover: 'auto',
                          gridLineColor: 'rgba(120, 130, 140, 0.28)',
                          gridTextColor:'#96a2b4',
                          resize: true
                        });

                          }
                      });
                  });
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Please reformulate.

Comment: this code working when i select value in select box i need to show data in load page (when i refresh page ) i'm not good in english  so much :)

Comment: when your page loaded, does your select box have any value selected by default ?

Comment: yes has a default  value